# ThreeJS 3D сцена. Как поворачивать текст всех меток лицом на камеру?

Tags: typescript, angular, three.js

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Object3D } from 'three';
import * as TrackballControls from 'three-trackballcontrols';
```

```
  public textLabels = [];

  draw3DAxes() {
    const dir1 = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );
    const dir2 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
    const dir3 = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
    const origin = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
    const length = 70;
    const hex = 0x000000;
    const headLength = 6;
    const headWidth = 1.5;
    const arrowHelper1 = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir1, origin, length, hex, headLength, headWidth );
    const arrowHelper2 = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir2, origin, length, hex, headLength, headWidth );
    const arrowHelper3 = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir3, origin, length, hex, headLength, headWidth );
    this.scene.add( arrowHelper1 );
    this.scene.add( arrowHelper2 );
    this.scene.add( arrowHelper3 );
  }

  setText(text, size, posX, posY, posZ, weight = .01): void {

    const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
    loader.load('assets/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', (font) => {
        const geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( text, {
          font,
          size,
          height: .3,
          curveSegments: 12,
          bevelEnabled: true,
          bevelThickness: 0.015,
          bevelSize: weight,
          bevelSegments: 5,
        });

        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        }));
        geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        geometry.boundingBox.getCenter(mesh.position).multiplyScalar(0);
        geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( posX, posY, posZ ));

        this.scene.add(mesh);
        this.textLabels.push(mesh);
      });
  }

  render() {
    this.controls.update();

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.render();
      this.textLabels.map(mesh => mesh.quaternion.copy(this.camera.quaternion));
    });
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
}
this.draw3DAxes();
this.setText('Hello Honey', 2, -5, 72, 7);
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => this.render());
```

на "3D сцене" много текстовых меток (вот таких как выше в примере)
Проблема: 
при использовании строки

```
this.textLabels.map(mesh => mesh.quaternion.copy(this.camera.quaternion));
```

текст поворачивается на камеру но открепляется от 3D сцены (появляется отдельная "2D сцена" текстовых меток)
а без этой строки текст является частью сцены и перемещается вместе с ней (вращение, зум и прочее) НО не поворачивается на камеру.
Нужно не открепляя текст от 3D сцены поворачивать его все время "лицом" на камеру.

Comment: я обычно рисую такой текст оверлеем, при помощи html+css

Comment: делал и так, но очень много меток (на всех 3х плоскостях), плохо зуммится, сильно зависит от CSS (сцена не на всю страницу).
делал по примеру: https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-align-html-elements-to-3d.html

Comment: А почему вместо задания позиции для меша, типа `mesh.position.set(posX, posY, posZ)`, применяется матрица трансляции к геометрии?

Comment: если честно уже даже не помню часть "какой борьбы" этот кусок кода.
НО это сработало! Спасибо!
(ставьте это в ответ :))

Comment: Был рад помочь :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, имеет смысл вместо вот этой части кода:

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
geometry.boundingBox.getCenter(mesh.position).multiplyScalar(0);
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( posX, posY, posZ ));
```

использовать такое:

```
geometry.center();
mesh.position.set(posX, posY, posZ);
```